# program for nested if else statement in c

Tags: c

I have very basic program in c for calculating grade but it's not running properly please anybody help, here is code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

int main()  
{ 
        int test1 ,test2,assignment1 , assignment2; 

        printf("Please enter the first test mark: ");      
        scanf("%f", &test1); 
        printf("You entered: %f \n", test1);

        printf("Please enter the second test mark: ");      
        scanf("%f", &test2); 
        printf("You entered: %f \n",test2); 

        printf("Please enter the first assignment mark: ");      
        scanf("%f", &assignment1); 
        printf("You entered: %f \n", assignment1); 

        printf("Please enter the second assignment mark: ");      
        scanf("%f", &assignment2); 
        printf("You entered: %f \n", assignment2); 

/* Now using nested ifs the program will use the calculate the average of the entered numbers and will 
   determine what the final mark is for the student */ 

        if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '100>80') 
          printf ("You got an A! \n");
        else 
          if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '79>70') 
          printf ("You got a B! \n"); 
        else 
          if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '69>60') 
             printf ("You got a C! \n");
        else 
          if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '59>50') 
             printf ("You got a D! \n");        
        else 
          if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '49>0') 
            printf ("You got an F! \n"); 
        else 
          if (test1,test2 == '50>0') 
              printf ("You got an F! \n"); 
        else 
          if ((assignment1, assignment2) == '50>0') 
              printf ("You got a  ! \n");                
        else 
           printf ("INVALID MARK! \n"); 
      return 0;
}
```

here is output.[image]

Comment: [You should compile with warnings.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d153a2a9b687ba8e)

Comment: Do not post screenshots! Instead paste the relevant text.

Comment: Why did you tag a C question [tag:c++]? There is no such language as "C/C++".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: "its not run properly" is an invalid problem statement.

Comment: For some specific input, what is your actual and expected output (*as text*)?

Comment: First lesson in C programming courses should be "how to properly indent and format my source code". Second lesson: "how to properly ask on stack overflow" .

Comment: What really is this ? Not valid statements  . I recommend you to start reading a good book for C.  Code has UB ....

Comment: No problem description other than "not run properly", mixing C and C++, confusion of `''` with `""`, no indentation, strange use of the comma operator... There are just too many things wrong with this question and with the code.

Comment: @BibiTahira The program you provided only vaguely resembles C. You may want to pick up a real tutorial or book on C first. You will make progress faster than via Stack Overflow, which can only provide little bits of information at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int test1 ,test2,assignment1 , assignment2;` to

`float test1 ,test2,assignment1 , assignment2;`

Answer (score 0):

Although the syntax you've submitted compiles and builds, it does so with several warnings.  The evaluation lines for example compile, but do not do what you intend.
The statement:

```
if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '100>80')//  '100>80' ??
```

For example would make more sense if written like this:

```
if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 >= 80)//A
```

And:

```
if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 == '79>70')
```

changed to:

```
if (((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 > 70) &&
    ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 <= 79))) //B
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

int main(){ 

    int test1 ,test2,assignment1 , assignment2; 

    printf("Please enter the first test mark: ");      
    scanf("%d", &test1); 
   printf("You entered: %d \n", test1);

    printf("Please enter the second test mark: ");      
    scanf("%d", &test2); 
    printf("You entered: %d \n",test2); 

    printf("Please enter the first assignment mark: ");      
    scanf("%d", &assignment1); 
    printf("You entered: %d \n", assignment1); 

    printf("Please enter the second assignment mark: ");      
    scanf("%d", &assignment2); 
    printf("You entered: %d \n", assignment2); 

    if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 > 100  ||
         test1 < 0 || test2 < 0 || 
         assignment1 < 0 || assignment2 < 0)
        printf ("INVALID MARK!\n"); 

    else  if ((test1 + test2  > 0) && (test1 + test2  < 50)) 
        printf ("You got an F! \n"); 

    else  if ((assignment1 + assignment2 > 0) 
        && (assignment1 + assignment2 < 50)) 
        printf ("You got a  ! \n");

    else if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 >= 80) 
        printf ("You got an A! \n"); 

    else if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 >= 70) 
        printf ("You got a B! \n"); 

    else  if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 >= 60) 
        printf ("You got a C! \n"); 

    else  if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4 >= 50) 
         printf ("You got a D! \n"); 

    else  if ((test1+test2+assignment1+assignment2)/4  >= 0) 
        printf ("You got an F! \n"); 

   else 
        printf ("INVALID MARK! \n"); 

   return 0; 

}
```